# How to recompile official OpenSUSE kernel & initrd?

Tags: kernel, opensuse

But it is not okay. I want all of the suse patches applied, I want an official initrd to be generated, and I want to make rpms from all of them. So, I want to recompile the kernel just as the SuSE does.

How is it possible? The simple `make rpm` solution in the kernel config is not enough, it doesn't generate an initrd. I think, practically it should be some like a clone from a central suse kernel repository, and then a source rpm recompilation. But I didn't found anything on the net about this. So, what to do?

Comment: [This](http://doc.opensuse.org/) might help as well as `mkinitrd(8)` If you want to recompile the kernel that way it is done in factory, then look at your `/boot/config-` file

Comment: @SailorCire Thank you your answer, but it is only the list of the included/needed drivers/features, it has none from my wishlist and it is only a very small part of the official suse recompilation.

Comment: Initrd is typically not generated when building a kernel RPM. It is generated while a kernel RPM is *installed*, using kernel modules from the kernel RPM + configuration files local to the system. So there is no "official initrd" except maybe the one used to boot the OS installer.

Comment: @telcoM Yes, so is it on my debian-based distros. Is it so also on OpenSUSE? If yes, you could write an answer; although the kernel recompilation part will be still missing.

Comment: I don't have an OpenSuSE test VM at hand right now; but I have some SLES ones, and I can confirm SLES 15 uses `dracut` to create its initrd/initramfs on installation of a kernel RPM. I'd bet OpenSuSE does the same. For kernel recompilation, my first guess would be to take the official OpenSuSE kernel *source RPM*, and run `rpmbuild -rb` (from package `rpm-build`) on it, just like the recompilation of any source RPM on any RPM-based distribution. The result should include at least a kernel RPM package equivalent to the official OpenSUSE one, plus maybe some debug info RPMs etc.